What's the best way to get the derived class from a base type pointer?
I tried two different ways to get a pointer to the derived class from a base pointer. One is:
struct BaseClass {
protected:
    int offset_of_derived;
public:
    template <typename T>
    T* getAs() { return (T*)((char*)this + offset_of_derived); }
protected:
    char* getBasePtr() { return (char*)this; }
};

template <typename T>
struct DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    DerivedClass() : BaseClass() { this->offset_of_derived = (char*)this - BaseClass::getBasePtr();  }

};

Also there's no need for std::launder because all I'm doing is casting from char and back, and to and from Base - Derived, right?

If you know there is a derived object then static_cast will do the job, otherwise use dynamic_cast.  Given the above, I guess I don't understand the question.

I don't think either works if you have more than one level of inheritance.  I also shudder to think of how this would work if you need to deal with multiple or diamond inheritance.

Generally speaking, and as you hopefully already knows, whenever you feel the need to do an old C-style explicit conversion (the cast to char*) you should take it as a sign that you're probably is doing something wrong. What is the actual and underlying problem you're trying to solve? Just plain down-casting? Then why can't you use the C++ casting operators mentioned by @RichardCritten?

@Jarod42 Oh right, that's a mistake.

The best way is to not need casts to derived classes at all and to use proper virtual functions in the baseclass to do the work for you. Portable code should also not assume anything about vtables or their layout/offset. All in all it seems your are just trying to outsmart yourself now. So go back to basics, remember the Liskov principle,  and do a redesign of your inheritance structure with a pure abstract baseclass somewhere.

FYI: std::is_base_of and virtual base class It demonstrates a derived_cast() function template which applies static_cast() if possible and dynamic_cast() otherwise. This is handy for the situation where you know that a base class pointer points to an instance of a certain derived class (or is a nullptr). The dynamic_cast is needed if virtual inheritance is involved.


"What's the best way to get the derived class from a base type pointer?"

You seem to attempt to manually implement what the language already offers out of the box.
There are 2 relevant language constructs that you can use:

The most powerful (but a little less efficient due to a runtime check) is dynamic_cast. it:

Safely converts pointers and references to classes up, down, and sideways along the inheritance hierarchy.

If you are not sure what type in the hirarchy is your object, just use dynamic_cast. It will return a null pointer if the conversion you requested is invalid so yu can always check yourself.

If you are sure the object is actually a derived one, you can use static_cast (which does not incur a runtime check):

A downcast can also be performed with static_cast, which avoids the
cost of the runtime check, but it is only safe if the program can
guarantee (through some other logic) that the object pointed to by
expression is definitely Derived.

Note that if you use static_cast with object which is not the expected derived, the behavior is undefined.


Usage examples for dynamic_cast:
BaseClass * p1 = get_object_pointer();  // some function that returns a pointer to an object in the hirarchy
DerivedClass * p2 = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass*>(p1);  // p2 will be a null pointer if conversion is invalid

Usage examples for static_cast:
BaseClass * p1 = new DerivedClass;
DerivedClass * p2 = static_cast<DerivedClass*>(p1);  // OK - we know p1 points to DerivedClass

Or if you want to have it as a method template in BaseClass then as suggested by @RichardCritten you could add:
template <typename T> 
T* getAs() { return dynamic_cast<T*>( this ); } // or use `static_cast` under the limitations explained above

